# Interactive SVG in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, svg, dynamic

I want to implement interactive svg in Angular Js application. Here is a glimpse of Svg which I will be using. I Know how to use an Svg in angular but the purpose of this question is not this. I want to make it dynamic. Like when I click "Punjab", the svg zooms in and show me regions, and upon clicking a specific region , it shows me the data which i will be getting through backend. So I am just curious, is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement you can use google map which can be easily integrated with Angular. Also I suggest to check D3.js.

Its Javascript library for creating SVG dynamically and can be easily integrated via Angular directives. There are plenty of examples available for the same.